# burpees for weight loss

Tags: weight-loss, ketogenic-diet

I do 200 burpees every day. 20 sets of 10, with 15 sec rest between sets. I am not losing any weight. Is it possible that I'm doing them wrong? Would doing them more precisely be more effective? I also do 40 minutes of cardio on my elliptical every day. I keep my calories under 1300/day and I am following a low carb diet. I have lost 55 pounds, with about 45 to reach my goal. I have hit a plateau and keep gaining/losing the same 5 pounds.

Comment: Provide some details about yourself if you don't mind - height, weight,etc. Under 1300 seems unhealthy.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, you're not doing them incorrectly.  Weight loss plateaus are as common as training plateaus.  The body tends to adapt to weight loss and training stresses.  That means you'll need to devise a new plan to kick start your progress.  That might mean trying different exercises.  And, if you aren't keeping a food journal, you should start.  Guessing at your caloric intake when trying to lose weight is counter productive.  You must have a good handle on the calories you are consuming in order to make any necessary adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise increasing your reps per set (not total reps)

You likely aren't pushing yourself enough and your body has adapted to this particular workout to the point that it has become too easy to really be effective

Try to do sets of 20 reps instead until you reach 200. Even if you need to increase your rest time that's ok. But you should feel very exerted in the last reps of your sets.

Once a week, following a day or two of complete rest, try to best your personal time record for doing a set of 40.. measure the time it takes you to complete those reps with good form and then try to best that time the next week.

Also make sure you are doing proper form.. go on youtube and watch the form. I see a lot of people entirely skip the pushup portion of the burpee and still call it a burpee.. that's not a burpee. Make sure both your feet actually leave the ground together in the jump portion, even if only a centimeter or two.

Lastly, for optimal fat loss try to do your cardio (in this case burpees) in the morning while in a fasted state. Then following the workout, remain fasted for as long as you can handle it.